# Reporting profile-guided compilation to the source code

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, gcc, compilation, branch-prediction

In this question I will focus on Visual Studio 2012 and GCC 4.7

On the one hand, profile-guided compilation optimizes branch prediction by instrumenting the code at run-time, and then using this information during a second compilation. On the other hand, many compilers provide extensions to hint to the compiler which branch will most-likely be taken: GCC provides `__builtin_expect` and Visual Studio provides `__assume`.

Is there a way to extract the profile-guided information (of either compiler) so as to be able to rewrite the code using both compiler extensions? The goal would be to provide an "optimized" source code for people willing to recompile their own version of the binary.

Comment: Note that `__assume` doesn't tell the compiler "this expression is likely to be true," it tells the compiler "this expression is always true."  There's a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this information using `gcov`.

Compile the sources like:

```
gcc -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs x.c
```

Run the executable

```
./a.out
```

Run `gcov -b` on a source file. The option `-b` tells it to generate branch probability information.

```
gcov -b x.c
```

`gcov` will create text file `x.c.gcov`, which will contain the required information, here's a sample:

```
        -:    5:int
function foo called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        1:    6:foo (unsigned int N)
        -:    7:{
        1:    8:  int i, s = 0;
        -:    9:
    10001:   10:  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
branch  0 taken 99%
branch  1 taken 1% (fallthrough)
        -:   11:    {
    10000:   12:      if ((rand () % 100) < 30)
call    0 returned 100%
branch  1 taken 30% (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 70%
     3027:   13:        s++;
        -:   14:      else
     6973:   15:        s--;
        -:   16:    }
        -:   17:
        1:   18:  return s;
        -:   19:}
```